# percent of cpu quota (actually) used by a container

Tags: docker

I'm relatively new to docker. I'm trying to get the percent of cpu quota (actually) used by a container. Is there a default metric emitted by one of the endpoints or is it something that I will have to calculate with other metrics? Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at `docker stats`? That is bound to an API endpoint only

Comment: Yes, I did. However, that provides static values for `cpu.quota` and `cpu.period` I believe. The values the container is started with. However, I'm looking for values that indicate the actual usage of CPU on a per container basis.

Answer (score 0):

`docker stats --no-stream
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %    (rest of line truncated)
949e2a3724e6        practical_shannon   8.32%    (truncated)`

As mentioned in the comment from @asuresh4, above, **docker stats** appears to give the ACTUAL cpu utilization, not the configured values. The output here is from `Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6`

--no-stream means run stats once, not continuously as it normally does. As you might guess, you can also ask for stats on a single container (specify the container name or id).

In addition to CPU %, MEM USAGE / LIMIT, MEM %, NET I/O, and BLOCK I/O are also shown.